# Changing enemy direction when back on the ground

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So right now the enemy keeps going forward forever. I want to change it so it travels back to the starting point once it hits the ground. In the same arc just the other direction.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
 
public class Enemy : Enemy_Damage
{
    [SerializeField] private float range;     // The range of movement for the object
    [SerializeField] private float speed;     // The speed at which the object moves
 
    private BoxCollider2D boxCollider;
    private Vector3 startPosition;
    private float Xdirection = 1f; // 1 for moving right, -1 for moving left
    private float Ydirection = 1f;
 
    private void Start()
    {
        boxCollider = GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
        startPosition = transform.position;
    }
 
    private void Update()
    {
 
        var offset = Time.time * speed;
        float newPosition = Mathf.PingPong(offset, range);
        Vector3 targetPosition = startPosition + new Vector3(Xdirection * offset, Ydirection * newPosition, 0);
 
        // Move the object
        transform.position = targetPosition;
 
        float threshold = 0.1f; // Threshold value for the comparison
 
        /*
        if (Mathf.Abs(transform.position.y - startPosition.y) < threshold)
        {
            Xdirection *= -1f;
        }
        */
 
    }
}
```

I tried the commented out code. But it either doesn't do anything or it makes the enemy disappear.